# Displaying Data from (.txt) in ListView C#

Tags: c#, listview

Actually I don't know what to call this but still I will try my best to explain my problem.

I have a text file saved on my desktop C:\users\Dell\partition.txt. It has data as follows

```
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name         Flags
 1      524kB   3670kB  3146kB               proinfo
 2      3670kB  8913kB  5243kB               nvram
 3      8913kB  19.4MB  10.5MB  ext4         protect1
 4      19.4MB  29.9MB  10.5MB  ext4         protect2
 5      29.9MB  30.4MB  524kB                lk
 6      30.4MB  30.9MB  524kB                para
 7      30.9MB  47.7MB  16.8MB               boot
 8      47.7MB  64.5MB  16.8MB               recovery
 9      64.5MB  72.9MB  8389kB               logo
10      72.9MB  73.9MB  1049kB               yl_params
```

I want to display this on ListView in C# Winforms to get some output like this

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlfSv.png)

I have seen some Softwares doing it but didn't find their sources. So is there any way to do it in C# Winforms.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: But did you even try to solve your problem or are just asking us to write code for you? There thousands tutorials on how to populate a ListView, just follow one of them and, if you have a problem, ask a question presenting your attempt to code your requirement.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but even I don't know what problem I am facing. That's why posted here for a help.

Comment: I have code once this is reopened.  Or create new posting and I will respond.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you need is not a ListView. That control is a DataGridView and what you need is to load what seems to be a tab separated CSV file onto it. You can make use of something like this:

```
private DataTable GetDataTableFromCsv(string path, bool isFirstRowHeader)
{
    string header = isFirstRowHeader ? "Yes" : "No";

    string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);

    string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" + fileName + "]";

    using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
              @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly + 
              ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
    using(OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
    using(OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

And then when you need to load the DataGridView, just call it this way:

```
YourDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
YourDataGridView.DataSource = GetDataTableFromCsv("C:\users\Dell\partition.txt", true);
```